# Eclipse API: How to batch resource changes for IJavaProject creation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

**(NOTE: SOLUTION IS BELOW)**

I am trying to create an `IJavaProject` while batching the resource change events, yet I am getting the following exception:

`Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Cannot nest 'JavaProject/src' inside 'JavaProject'. To enable the nesting exclude 'src/' from 'JavaProject']`

The exception is thrown on the line where I am setting the raw class path a second time (commented in the code below, towards the end).

Without batching (ie: removing the `IWorkspaceRunnable` and related code), my IJavaProject is initialized just fine. So, how can I create an IJavaProject with batched resource change events?

Here is my code, and my method for creating the `IJavaProject` is largely taken from [here](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/JDT_Tutorial:_Creating_Eclipse_Java_Projects_Programmatically):

```
public static IJavaProject getJavaProjectBatched(final IProject project,
                                                 final String sourceFolderPath,
                                                 final String binFolderPath)
    throws CoreException
{
    IWorkspaceRunnable r = new IWorkspaceRunnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run(@Nullable IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
        {
            if (!project.exists())
                ResourceUtility.createProject(project);

            IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
            description.setNatureIds(new String[] {JavaCore.NATURE_ID});
            project.setDescription(description, null);

            IFolder binFolder = project.getFolder(binFolderPath);
            binFolder.create(false, true, null);

            final IFolder sourceFolder = project.getFolder(sourceFolderPath);
            sourceFolder.create(false, true, null);

            final IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
            javaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);

            List<IClasspathEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            IVMInstall vmInstall = JavaRuntime.getDefaultVMInstall();
            LibraryLocation[] locations = JavaRuntime.getLibraryLocations(vmInstall);
            for (LibraryLocation element: locations)
            {
                entries.add(JavaCore.newLibraryEntry(element.getSystemLibraryPath(), null, null));
            }
            IPackageFragmentRoot root = javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(sourceFolder);
            IClasspathEntry[] oldEntries = javaProject.getRawClasspath();
            IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[oldEntries.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(oldEntries, 0, newEntries, 0, oldEntries.length);
            newEntries[oldEntries.length] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(root.getPath());
            // add libs to project class path
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(entries.toArray(new IClasspathEntry[entries.size()]),
                                        null);
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null);// Exception is thrown HERE!!!
        }
    };

    project.getWorkspace().run(r, null, IWorkspace.AVOID_UPDATE, null);
    @SuppressWarnings("null") @NonNull IJavaProject jp = JavaCore.create(project);
    return jp;
}
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**

With `nitind`'s help in the answer below, I worked out the batched version that suits my needs. In short - this is how to create an IJavaProject that mimics Eclipse's internal resource tree representation.

This was part of my broader question, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494353/eclipse-pde-mimicking-iresourcechangeevents-for-ijavaproject-creation-between-p) Thanks for the help.

```
public static IJavaProject getJavaProjectBatched(final IProject project, final String sourceFolderPath,
                                                 final String binFolderPath) throws CoreException
{
    IWorkspaceRunnable r = new IWorkspaceRunnable()
    {
         @Override public void run(@Nullable IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
        {
             if (!project.exists())
                 ResourceUtility.createProject(project);

             IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
             description.setNatureIds(new String[] {JavaCore.NATURE_ID});
             project.setDescription(description, null);

             IFolder binFolder = project.getFolder(binFolderPath);
             binFolder.create(false, true, null);
             final IFolder sourceFolder = project.getFolder(sourceFolderPath);
             sourceFolder.create(false, true, null);

             final IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
             javaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);

            IPackageFragmentRoot root = javaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(sourceFolder);
            IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[1];
            newEntries[0] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(root.getPath());
            javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, null); 
        }
    };

    project.getWorkspace().run(r, null,IWorkspace.AVOID_UPDATE, null);
    @SuppressWarnings("null") @NonNull IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
    return javaProject;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that you cannot have the project itself and one of its folders on the Java Build Path unless you're excluding that folder from the entry that represents the entire project. Since you're creating the project, skip the bit with the oldEntries.

Comment: Thank you, I now have a solution that works for me. All I needed was to create an IJavaProject that matches Eclipse's internal representation of Resource Change Events when creating an IJavaProject (I have a broader question referenced above). I am still a bit unsure because I no longer needed the `IVMInstall` or `LibraryLocation` (new solution above). Is this okay because I am creating a new project from scratch, or should the new IJavaProject have a reference to the library locations?